# android explicit intent by name not resolving to other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have 2 apps that are used in conjunction with one another. I want to create a button that launches app A from app B so I am creating an intent like so in app B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.org.orgmobile.android.action.ACTION_CUSTOM");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

where `url` is `https://org.org.com/mobile/Support/action/org/ActionEnumValue/?a=123`

the intent filter I have declared in app A's manifest is like so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.org.orgmobile.android.action.ACTION_CUSTOM"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="org.org.com"/>
    <data android:pathPrefix="/mobile/Support/action/${manifestplaceholderattr}.*/ActionEnumValue/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

and `manifestplaceholderattr` is an empty string.

I am getting

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.org.orgmobile.android.action.ACTION_CUSTOM dat=https://org.org.com/... flg=0x20000000 }
                            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1936)
                            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
                            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
                            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
```

What am I overlooking here? I have tried using `pathPattern` instead of path prefix with no success.

Edit: to provide more detail, I don't just want to launch that specific activity, I want to match the specific intent associated with that activity to launch the activity. I don't want to launch the activity directly because in the case that the user's app is out of date because it won't have the desired behavior.

Comment: Could you please provide a full version of the error message.

Comment: I added the stack trace to the question but it doesn't provide much more insight

Comment: Yeah, I was actually hoping to see the full version of this part: `dat=https://org.org.com/... flg=0x20000000 }`

Comment: I caught it in the debugger and unfortunately that's all there is

Comment: Post more of your AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this through Package manager as below.

```
 PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app B package name here");
        if (intent == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Package manager checks if app with the given package name is installed, if exists it launches the app else it throws NameNotFoundException

Comment: the catch is that I don't just want to launch the package just if it's present, I want to match the intent filter exactly. If the user has an older version of the client that doesn't support this action then I don't want to launch the activity

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pathPattern` instead of `pathPrefix`. Also you should use `.*` instead of `*` at the end of the pattern:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/mobile/Support/action/${manifestplaceholderattr}.*/ActionEnumValue/.*"/>
```

This may also not work. If I recall, `pathPattern` isn't a real regular expression and you may not be able to match the URL like this. Try it and see. If this doesn't work, you'll probably need to rely on just the first part of the path. Let me know how it goes.

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#path) on `path`, `pathPattern` and `pathPrefix`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use code as below to launch other App using custom action.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.org.orgmobile.android.action.ACTION_CUSTOM");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also make sure both of your application is installed. Also it is better to have check as below to make sure application exists on the phone to handle such Intent.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

Comment: the intent still fails to resolve to the other app's activity. I'm at a loss here.